# How to handle useEffect only on condition

Tags: reactjs, api, request, use-effect

I am doing a Gastby website.

The problem is that Gatsby resets the state (unmounts the component) when the route changes. To avoid this, you can generate a wrapper that applies to all pages.

In this wrapper I have to make a set of api requests, only if user is logged in.

So I came up with this, which seems wrong

```
const Watcher = ({ isLogged }) => {      
  return (
    <>
      {isLogged && <Requests />}
      <Header />
      {children}
    </>
  )
};
```

and then in the Requests component

```
const Requests = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    // some requests go here
  }, [someVar1])  
  useEffect(() => {
    // some requests go here
  }, [someVar2])  
  useEffect(() => {
    // some other requests go here
  }, [someVar3])    
  return null
}
```

It works but looks awkward. I know I can pass all the useEffects pieces of code to the Watcher.js, but it is not neat either, as there are several useEffects, and would have apply the condition to see if the user is logged in on each, plus, re-run each useEffect when the logged in state changes.

Comment: Are these requests only called once (after the user logs in)? Or do they get called multiple times throughout your app?

Comment: @DylanKerler they get called once after the user logs in. The problem is that they need to be on the wrapper, else gatsby re makes the request on every route change

Answer (score 0):

You can combine all that in one `useEffect` as you asked , on condition.

Of course you have to add other dependecies like functions used into the `useEffect`

Example here:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(someVar1 === 'somevalue')
        // some requests go here
    if(someVar2 === 'something')
        // some requests go here
    if(someVar3)
        // some other requests go here
},[someVar1, someVar2, someVar3])
```

Also as an alternative, I suggest you use `redux-saga` and send an action to it only when the user logs in.

[Documentation here](https://redux-saga.js.org/)